# jQuery: Elastic header/image with zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm sure you all have seen this iOS style on the header images in some apps where you pull to zoom and its like an Elastic image.

I'm trying to achieve this in `jquery` and maybe with the help of some CSS only.

This has been done using `angularjs` but I'm not familiar with angularjs so I was wondering if anyone has or know a simple jquery example?

This is the angularjs example:

https://codepen.io/olach/pen/NqrYQL

If you pull the image and then release it, you will see the effect.

I also found other projects that uses `cordova and gulp` but again, not entirely sure what gulp is so I can't even use that.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together this for you. Check this fiddle out:

https://jsfiddle.net/RCD_Y/sj9xuk1p/16/

Or this snippet (works better on the fiddle for sure):

```js
var dragging = false;
var maxDrag = 170;

var prevScrollTime = -1;
var prevScrollTop = -1;
var originalTime = -1;
var originalTop = -1;
var originalY = -1;

$("body").on("mousedown touchstart", (e) => {
  dragging = true;
  originalY = e.pageY;
  if (!originalY) {
    originalY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
  }
  originalTime = prevScrollTime = Date.now();
  originalTop = prevScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
});

$("body").on("mouseup touchend", (e) => {
  dragging = false;
  $(".img-container").animate({
    height: "75vw",
    width: "100vw",
    left: 0
  }, 300, "easeOutCubic");
  if (!e.pageY) e.pageY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
  if (Date.now() - prevScrollTime >= 60) return;
  var veloc = (document.body.scrollTop - originalTop) / (Date.now() - originalTime);
  var targetTop = document.body.scrollTop + $("body").height() * veloc * Math.abs(veloc);
  var pageEnd = $(".parent").height() - $("body").height();
  if (targetTop < 0) {
    $("body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, {
      duration: (document.body.scrollTop + targetTop) / (document.body.scrollTop - targetTop) * 400,
      easing: "linear",
      queue: false,
      complete: () => {
        drag(-targetTop / 8, 400, () => {
          $(".img-container").animate({
            height: "75vw",
            width: "100vw",
            left: 0
          }, 300, "easeOutCubic");
        });
      }
    });
  } else if (targetTop > pageEnd) {
    $("body").animate({
      scrollTop: targetTop
    }, (targetTop - pageEnd) / targetTop * 400, "easeOutCubic");
    $(".parent").animate({
      height: $(".parent").height() + (targetTop - pageEnd) / 64
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: (targetTop - pageEnd) / targetTop * 400,
      complete: () => {
        $(".parent").animate({
          height: $(".parent").height() - (targetTop - pageEnd) / 64
        }, 300, "easeOutCubic");
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("body").animate({
      scrollTop: targetTop
    }, 600, "easeOutCubic");
  }
});

$("body").on("mousemove touchmove", (e) => {
  if (dragging) {
    if (!e.pageY) {
      e.pageY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    }
    if (document.body.scrollTop == 0 && e.pageY > originalY) {
      drag(e.pageY - originalY, 1);
    } else {
      document.body.scrollTop = prevScrollTop - e.pageY + originalY;
      prevScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
      prevScrollTime = Date.now();
    }
  }
});

function drag(x, y, callback) {
  //Play with the constants to achieve different easing effects
  var incValue = maxDrag * 2 / 3 - Math.pow(maxDrag * 2 / 3, -(x - maxDrag * 4) / maxDrag / 4)
    //The original image is 16:12, change code to match target aspect ratio
  $(".img-container").animate({
    width: $("body").width() + incValue,
    height: $("body").width() * 0.75 + incValue * 0.75,
    left: -incValue / 2
  }, {
    duration: y,
    easing: "easeOutCubic",
    queue: false,
    complete: callback
  });
}

$(window).scroll(() => {
  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop < 0) scrollTop = 0;
  if (scrollTop >= 0 && scrollTop < $(".img-container").height()) {
    $(".img-container").css("top", scrollTop / 2);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vw;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#info {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: -apple-system, "Helvetica", "Arial", serif;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/responsive/cover/main/desktop/2016/11/03/636137866789556986-167666954_city-skyline-drawing-wallpaper-2.jpg" draggable="false" />
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur egestas convallis enim quis pharetra. Etiam interdum viverra ligula, ut aliquam sem cursus eu. Etiam vehicula consequat porta. Sed iaculis eget nisl id rhoncus. Quisque cursus turpis vel
    nunc molestie, sed hendrerit metus varius. Suspendisse hendrerit dapibus purus, vestibulum iaculis ligula tristique non. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam sed volutpat erat. Donec mauris libero, posuere ut metus id, molestie varius arcu. Maecenas
    sed neque augue. Vestibulum tempus dictum semper. Phasellus maximus nisi in dolor ultrices condimentum. Sed venenatis sollicitudin suscipit. Integer aliquam mattis tellus, in pulvinar ligula rutrum ac.
    <br />
    <br /> Morbi elementum nec lorem nec blandit. Donec varius nulla eu nibh aliquet, a euismod ligula interdum. Morbi finibus erat leo, congue tempor nibh lobortis ac. Duis tempor ante vitae eros molestie scelerisque at non ex. Integer auctor a odio dapibus
    dapibus. Vivamus eget hendrerit magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus cursus bibendum egestas. Nullam vel nulla quis lorem dapibus sagittis. Suspendisse lacinia ligula sem, sed
    ullamcorper mauris euismod a.
  </div>
</div>
```

Use your cursor or finger to navigate around.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i dont think there is anyone here on SO crazy enough to write such an entire code for you.

However, like you mentioned, pointing you in the right direction would be helpfull.

I once builded exacly the same as you want to archieve. What i used was: **https://github.com/peachananr/fancy-scroll**

I think this github project is as close as you can get.

It does exacly the same as what iOS browsers do. You just have to fine tune it to meet your requirements.

Comment: that is far from what I am trying to achieve. not even close. thanks for the reply though.